# ColdFusion and saving Chinese chars and changing Admin settings

Tags: sql, unicode, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I need to be able to save Chinese chars in my active database with ColdFusion 9
I have already figured out how to do it set the field types to `NVARCHARS` and `NTEXT`.

I have checked off **Enable High ASCII characters and Unicode for data sources configured for non-Latin characters** under the Datasources section.

It works great but... here is the question.

Changing the option  **Enable High ASCII characters and Unicode for data sources configured for non-Latin characters**  - will this create any other downstream issue with the current application?  We will need to update the database structure - I am not sure what effect this option will have to my legacy code.

Comment: Hopefully you have a test environment since that's the only way to know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

That should not have any effect on your database or your code. It's just a setting on how the application server (coldfusion) communicates to your database server.

Comment: Those two statements seem quite contradictory.

Comment: I misread. I though it said 'future' applications, as if it would make the database server or application server different and unusable.